# Vue Trigger watch on mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue component below that I want to watch to trigger on when it's getting mounted.  How do I do that?

```js
Vue.component('check-mark', {
  name: 'check-mark',
  template: `<input :value="value"/>`,
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  mounted: async function () {
    //trigger this.value watch() here
  },
  watch: {
    value: function (value) {
      if (value == 'Y') {
        this.class = 'checked';
      } else {
        this.class = 'unchecked';
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354027/vue-js-how-to-fire-a-watcher-function-when-a-component-initializes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you might be better served by a computed in this case.

```
computed:{
  class(){
    return this.value === 'Y' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'
  }
}
```

But if you really want to use a watcher, abstract the code you do in the watch into a method and call it from mounted.

```
Vue.component('check-mark', {
  name: 'check-mark',
  template: `
    <input :value="value">
  `,
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data(){
    return {
      class: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    setClass(value){
      if (value == 'Y') {
        this.class = 'checked';
      } else {
        this.class = 'unchecked';
      } 
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.setClass(this.value)
  },
  watch: {
    value: function (value) {
      this.setClass(value)
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Excellent! I got it working with the computed function.

Answer (score 63):

As of Vue 2.0, there is now a way to do it in the watcher itself, using `immediate: true`.
*There's a minor caveat for when in the lifecycle this runs the watcher, see edit.*

> Before using this, **ensure you really need a watcher** rather than a **computed property**.
>
> There are many advantages to computed properties and more often than not they are the better solution.
>
> This functionality should only be used if computed properties are insufficient.
>
> In the specific case of the original question, a computed property for `class` would definitely be better, but posted this just in case other people stumble across this post with a case where a computed property won't do (as I did).

[Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) can be an object instead of just a function, and take property **`immediate`** that tells vue to run the watcher when the component is ***created*** (different from *mounted*).

The function that is run is then in the `handler` property.

So, in your example, your watcher could be:

```
watch: {
    value: {
        handler: function(value) {
            if (value == 'Y') {
                this.class = 'checked';
            } else {
                this.class = 'unchecked';
            }
        },
        immediate: true
    },
}
```

### *Edit*

It was pointed out in the comments that the `immediate` option triggers the watcher when the component is ***created*** rather than when ***mounted***. In simple cases, these can be seen as equivalent.
If you really want specifically the run when ***mounted*** functionality for a watcher, you could simply have the field you're watching be some dummy value, say `null` or `undefined`, and then actually initialize it in the `mounted()` hook. The above example would become:

```
data() {
    return {
        value: undefined
    }
},
mounted() {
    // Set value to actual initial value,
    // which will trigger the watcher
    this.value = 'Y';
},
watch: {
    value(value) {
        if (value == 'Y') {
            this.class = 'checked';
        } else {
            this.class = 'unchecked';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There'a a quite bad drawback in doing this: when called, the watched function will be called before vue's mount hook. That means that any useful data and properties (for ex $refs) won't be visible from the watch function.

Comment: @stratboy That may be the case, I'm not sure about that, but even if it is it would update again once that data was loaded, no?

Comment: Besides, this is simply another tool in the toolbox. It may not be appropriate for all use cases, but it certainly will be appropriate for some so I was just trying to present it as an alternative.

Comment: @scniro for the original questions specific case, a computed property is definitely the right choice, and besides which I answered this long after it was asked anyway.

Comment: The asker asked about calling the watcher on `mount` - this calls it on `created`. This is not exactly the same thing although it may work for most purposes.

Comment: I indeed needed a watcher! Thanks for this @obermillerk

Comment: wondering if using $nextTick inside the watcher will guarantee that the underlying code will execute after "mounted"?

Comment: if you're using $nextTick there's probably a better way to do it. I would also hazard a guess that it would not necessarily be the case that it would be mounted by then, but you should definitely check the docs if you really want to go that way

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when looking for this in **Vue3** with **script setup**.

Note that I didn't want to use the `immediate: true` option since I was using a **reference to a template element** that exists only after being mounted.

So I used the [`watchTriggerable`](https://vueuse.org/shared/watchtriggerable/) utility from [vue-use](https://vueuse.org/)

Here's what your example would look like:

```js
const props = defineProps<{
    value: boolean;
}>();

const className = ref("");

onMounted(() => {
    updateClass();
});

const { trigger: updateClass } = watchTriggerable(
    () => props.value,
    () => {
        className.value = props.value ? "checked" : "unchecked";
    }
);
```

⚠️ Note that with this example, you would be perfectly fine with the `immediate: true` option. Even better: using a computed. But it's for the example.

You'll need to install and import vue-use though:

```
pnpm install @vueuse/core
```

then import it in your component with

```js
import { watchTriggerable } from "@vueuse/core";
```