# Vue.js: How to fire a watcher function when a component initializes

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

Sometimes I need to call some function in response to a change in a data property. But, I also need that function to fire for the initial value of the data property.

The watcher does not fire when the component initializes since the property being watched technically hasn't changed yet. So, I end up putting the function in the `methods` object, and then calling that method in the watcher and the `mounted` hook.

Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedIndex: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    focusSelected() {
      this.$refs.input[this.selectedIndex].focus();
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selectedIndex() {
      this.focusSelected();
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.focusSelected();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="i in 4">
    <input ref="input"/>
    <button @click="selectedIndex = (i - 1)">Select</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to be able to have the watcher fire when the component initializes?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[Watchers in Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) have an option to provide an `immediate` value:

> Passing in `immediate: true` in the option will trigger the callback immediately with the current value of the expression

In this case, you could set a watcher in the `mounted` hook:

```js
new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedIndex: 0,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$watch('selectedIndex', (i) => {
      this.$refs.input[i].focus();
    }, { immediate: true });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="i in 4">
    <input ref="input"/>
    <button @click="selectedIndex = (i - 1)">Select</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You could also specify the `immediate` option for a watcher in the `watch` object like so:

```
watch: {
  foo: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(value) {
      this.bar = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the second solution will be fired when the component is created, but before it is mounted

Comment: The code above is written for vue2. Here are the docs for vue3: https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#watch