# Check if in created() vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

```
data() {
  return: {
     checkValue: false,
     loading: 'success',
 }
},
created() {
    if (this.loading == 'success') {
     this.checkValue = true;
    }
}


//template
    <div v-if="this.checkValue == true">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <a-form-item label="Photo Background Spotlight">
                     <a-radio-group
                        <a-radio value="1">Jony</a-radio>
                        <a-radio value="2">veart</a-radio>
                     </a-radio-group>
                 </a-form-item>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I gave `checkValue == true` in `created`. But it still doesn't show the template option radio.Where did I go wrong. Give me your opinion. Thank you

Comment: What if you use `<div v-if="checkValue">`? You don’t need to use `this` in your template and you can let v-if to evaluate the variable as truthy/falsy directly. Your code should technically work tho: can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: or you can use watcher with immediate option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354027/vue-js-how-to-fire-a-watcher-function-when-a-component-initializes

Comment: Remove `this.` from your template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `this` in a template.
Replace `<div v-if="this.checkValue == true">` with  `<div v-if="checkValue">`.
As the check value is of type `boolean` you don't need to check it for `true`.